# How to throw exception when there is extra parameters in request body spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

In my last project, there was a requirement for throwing exceptions when the request body contains extra parameters.

If the request will be like

```
{
   "test":"body",
    "name":"HR 1",
    "location":"Location"
}
```

where test parameter is unnecessary and I've to return a response that should be like

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-05-07T00:13:59.144657",
    "status": "500",
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "test : must not be provided",
    "path": "/api/departments/HR"
}
```

I've shared the answer. How I handled it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the application.properties I added this line.

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

This helps us to make deserialization fail on unknown properties and throw an exception which we can handle using **handleHttpMessageNotReadable**

create controller advice to handle exceptions

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity("Your Response Object", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

That's the solution.